# batch file to get and store the svn log in local directory

Tags: svn, shell, tortoisesvn, batch-file

The batch file i intend to use should actually produce the svnlog in XML format in my `C:\` drive.

But it shows an error that:

`The filename,directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`

My code:

```
     @echo off
     cls
     set SOURCE=https://xxxx//repos/trunk
     set SVN=C:\Program Files\subversion-cli
     set Des=C:\
    "%SVN%\svn.exe"
    /command:svn log --xml > %Des%svnlog.xml /path:"%SOURCE%" /closeonend:2
     pause
```

Require some guidance. Probably a rectification of my script as I am a beginner in scripting.

Comment: `/command:svn` is a part from another song - TSVN amd it's TortoiseProc backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
svn log --xml %SOURCE% > %Des%svnlog.xml
```

**OR**

```
TortoiseProc /command:log /path:"%SOURCE%" /outfile:%Des%svnlog.xml
```

(TBT!)